# Adding new line of multiple value React JS

Tags: reactjs, get, next.js, fetch

I want to add a new line of string to the map function.

My code looks like this :

```
<tbody>
    {" "}
    {dataTable.map((table) => {
        return (
            <tr key={table.id}>
                <th className="border-t-0 px-6 align-middle border-l-0 py-4 pt-4 pb-0 text-left flex items-center">
                    <Avatar name={table.title} size={30} round="25px" className="mr-2" color="#f9fbff" fgColor="#4987f3" />
                    <span className={"ml-3 font-bold light"}>{table.title} </span>{" "}
                </th>{" "}
                <td className="border-t-0 px-6 border-l-0 py-4 pt-4 pb-0"> {table.id} </td> {" "}
                <td className="border-t-0 px-6 border-l-0 py-4 pt-4 pb-0"> {table.footer} </td>{" "}
                <td className="border-t-0 px-6 border-l-0 py-4 pt-4 pb-0"> {table.description} </td> {" "}
                <td className="border-t-0 px-6 border-l-0 py-4 pt-4 pb-0"> <i className="fas fa-circle text-emerald-500 mr-2"></i>{" "} {table.tags} </td>{" "}
            </tr>
        );
    })}{" "}
</tbody>
```

for tags data, there is some value, and I want to add a new line for the value of every tag.

[image]

For the data :

```
[
  {
    "id": 936556,
    "category": 7,
    "title": "Gorgeous Cotton Fish",
    "description": "The Apollotech B340 is an affordable wireless mouse with reliable connectivity, 12 months battery life and modern design",
    "footer": "Gorgeous"
  },
  {
    "id": 874754,
    "category": 8,
    "title": "Unbranded Plastic Fish",
    "description": "The Football Is Good For Training And Recreational Purposes",
    "footer": "Practical",
    "tags": [
      "Music",
      "Kids",
      "Books",
      "Clothing",
      "Baby"
    ],
    "createdAt": "2021-09-10T01:39:35.109073+00:00"
  },
]
```

Comment: What is your `table.tags` look like?

Comment: Can you add more clarity? What is the value of `table.tags`? What do you actually want to show.

Comment: the value is a string, just like the screenshot.
and gets from json

Comment: You can add the actual value to the question. And what do you want to achieve. I can see that `dataTable` is an array. Each array item is an object and each of them has property `tags` : which is a string? Is that correct?

Comment: Yess @TusharShahi, it's a string, what I want to achieve is, the result of tags value can following the screenshot, because right now its just one line.

Comment: Ok. You will have to add the exact value of `data.tags` so we know

Comment: @TusharShahi I just add JSON data that I want to get. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

I think you need one more `map()` specifically for that one property. You can then use something like a `<p>` tag or maybe a `<span>` to show your data.

```
<tbody>
    {" "}
    {dataTable.map((table) => {
        return (
            <tr key={table.id}>
                <th className="border-t-0 px-6 align-middle border-l-0 py-4 pt-4 pb-0 text-left flex items-center">
                    <Avatar name={table.title} size={30} round="25px" className="mr-2" color="#f9fbff" fgColor="#4987f3" />
                    <span className={"ml-3 font-bold light"}>{table.title} </span>{" "}
                </th>{" "}
                <td className="border-t-0 px-6 border-l-0 py-4 pt-4 pb-0"> {table.id} </td> {" "}
                <td className="border-t-0 px-6 border-l-0 py-4 pt-4 pb-0"> {table.footer} </td>{" "}
                <td className="border-t-0 px-6 border-l-0 py-4 pt-4 pb-0"> {table.description} </td> {" "}
                <td className="border-t-0 px-6 border-l-0 py-4 pt-4 pb-0"> {table.tags.map((x) => <p><i className="fas fa-circle text-emerald-500 mr-2"></i>{" "} {x}</p>{" "}  );}
     </td>{" "}</tr>
        );
    })}{" "}
</tbody>
```